# The internal energy of a system is a single-valued function of the state variables viz. Pressure, volume, temperature etc

Tags: homework-and-exercises

In case of gas, any two of the variables P, T, V are sufficient to define completely its state. Why so?

Answer (score 0):

> Why so?

PV=nRT gives you the third.

By the way, the premise of your question is valid only for ideal gases at thermodinamical equilibrium and so is my answer.

---

For the purposes of your question, the generalization of the ideal gas law to include say the [Van der Waals forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_gas) is trivial in the sense that still you have a relation that links P, V, and T. A better counterexample is [magnetic gases](http://news.mit.edu/2009/magnetic-gas-0918) -- as long as you are willing to extrapolate the usage of 'gas' for Bose-Einstein condensates.

Comment: Alright, Thanks!!

Comment: I beg to differ with you, but the addition of the Van der Waal factor is not trivial if you want to solve problems involving real gases

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal gas, any two of the properties of temperature, pressure or volume, defines the third property in accordance with the equation of state of an ideal gas. For one mole of gas the equation of state is, $PV=RT$ where R is the universal gas constant.

For a real gas, there are intermolecular (Van der Waal) forces, and the equation of state becomes $PV=ZRT$ where $Z$ is called the "compressibility factor". $Z=1$ for an ideal gas. $Z$ does not equal 1 for a real real gas.

Hope this helps.